# Infinite loop in IE6 Print Preview

Tags: printing, html-table, internet-explorer-6, print-preview

I work on a web application hosted at over a hundred large sites that has as one of its requirements support for Internet Explorer 6 - not supporting IE6 is not an option as the organisations that use it are huge and that decision is out of my hands.

Users have discovered that printing certain pages is not possible, and having simplified one such page down to its core components I have found that it is a trivial piece of HTML causing this - it does not break IE7 or IE8 - is this a bug in IE6 and is there a way round it?  I would rather not release a new version of the software and distribute it, but it seems I may have to.

The HTML is below - the problem is caused by the height:100% in the inner table, and while I agree this is not the most elegant HTML, bear in mind this is a massively simplified version just to demonstrate the problem in it simplest form.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="HEIGHT:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src='blank650x408.gif' alt='left image'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src='blank364x405.gif'  alt='right image'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Viewing a print preview of this page in portrait mode doesn't give a problem, but switching to landscape causes a blank page to be shown, and at the top the page counts states "Page 1 of x" where x is a continually increasing number.  The images blank650x408 and blank364x405.gif are just black rectangles of the dimensions indicated by their name.